# Unable to hide keyboard for the field under SwiftyPickerPopover

Tags: ios, swift, swift4

There is a lot of help available for hiding keyboard and trust me I've applied every single method but nothing is working for me. I'm using [SwiftyPickerPopover](https://github.com/hsylife/SwiftyPickerPopover) a library that let me show a popover.

I've a view in which there are three text fields and the third one is date field on which I'm showing `SwiftyPickerPopover`. Inside the method `textFieldDidBeginEditing` I've done this:

```
func textFieldDidBeginEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {

        if textField.isEqual(setDateField) {
            self.view.endEditing(true)
            DatePickerPopover(title: "Select Date")
                .setDateMode(.date)
                .setSelectedDate(Date())
                .setDoneButton(title: "Select", color: UIColor (red: 26/255, green: 35/255, blue: 126/255, alpha: 1.0), action: { popover, selectedDate in
                    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
                    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd-MM-yyyy"
                    let convertedDate: String = dateFormatter.string(from: selectedDate)
                    textField.text = convertedDate
                })
                .setCancelButton(title: "Clear",color: UIColor (red: 236/255, green: 31/255, blue: 38/255, alpha: 1.0), action: { _,_ in
                    textField.text = ""
                })
                .appear(originView: textField, baseViewController: self)

        }
    }
```

I've also tried `textFieldShouldReturn` method but the keyboard stays. I'm also using `TPKeyboardAvoiding` for this view.

Comment: have u tried `resignFirstResponder()` on the textFiled ?

Comment: @SandeepBhandari ye I have but still it is not hiding keyboard.

Comment: try the answer I have posted lemme know if it helps